# Restkit addFetchRequestBlock crashes

Tags: ios, swift, restkit

So I've got the following code:

```
RKObjectManager.sharedManager().addFetchRequestBlock({
  url in

  // let pathMatcher = RKPathMatcher(path: "/v1/groups/")
  // var dict = NSDictionary?()
  // let match = pathMatcher.matchesPath(url.relativePath, tokenizeQueryStrings: false, parsedArguments: &dict)

  // if match {
  if let path = url.relativePath where path == "/v1/groups" {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: String(self))
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY member == %@", activeUser)
    return fetchRequest
  }

  return nil
})
```

It works, but as you can see it's not using the RKPathMatcher.

If I comment in the outcommented code, I get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'*** -[NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: nil argument'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but the dict part should be:

```
var dict: NSDictionary?
```

Though it doesn't look like you're using it so you can just set it to nil.

Comment: Ok, I will try. Well, I did try sending nil but couldnt get it to compile then.. I'll try later and get back!

Comment: i guess the flags haven't been added to tell swift if it can be nil

Comment: That didnt work :/ Crashes in `static NSUInteger RKNumberOfSlashesInString(NSString *string)`

Comment: Re-reading your question, if you don't have parameters to match against them an explicit comparison is more efficient anyway.